# BPEL to BPMN to be used in BPM engine

Tags: jbpm, bpel, business-process-management, bpmn

Is there a tool to convert **BPEL to BPMN** to be used in BPM engine?
I want to use the BPEL file in BPM engine to run the orchestration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any tool and i don't think you could do an automated conversion from BPEL to BPMN(2).
Here is a [paper](http://oryx-project.org/pub/Public/MatthiasWeidlich/bpel2bpmn.pdf) which explains the difficulties and reasons why such an tool can't be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There were some projects active in this area (for example the Oryx project), but due to conceptual mismatch of this two languages the work in this area was stopped. Here is one more [paper](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-364/paper15.pdf) about this topic. I was also looking for such a tool, but my search was not successful.